# Is there a more efficient query I can use

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if theres a better way to script out this update statement:

```
update table A
set item = (select itemA + ' - ' + itemB from table B where id = 1),
temp = (select itemA from table B where id = 1)
where sid = (select sItemId from table B where id = 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JOINS` to make it more efficient and `Alias` to make it more readable.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.item  = B.itemA + ' - ' + B.itemB 
   ,A.temp  = B.itemA 
FROM tableA A 
INNER JOIN tableB B ON A.[sid] = B.sItemId 
where B.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server specific syntax:

```
update a
set item = b.itemA + ' - ' + b.itemB,
    temp = b.itemA
from tableA a
     inner join tableB b on a.sid = b.sItemId
where b.id=1
```

Alternatively you can use MERGE:

```
merge into tableA as a
using tableB as b
on a.sid = b.sItemId and b.Id = 1
when matched then update set item = b.itemA + ' - ' + b.itemB, temp = b.itemA
;
```

The advantage of merge is that it is standard SQL syntax, and it will fail if an attempt is made to update the same record twice (the `update` with `join` will silently do only one of the updates). IIRC in later versions (with the respective compatibility level) `update` will fail as well. Also `merge` is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course better to use only one join instead of retrieving the same table (tableB) 3 times

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET tableA.item =tableB. itemA + ' - ' + tableB.itemB, 
tableA.temp = tableB.itemA ,
...
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.sid= tableB.sItemId And tableB.id =1
```